# rails simple_form bitmask attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have two questions about simple_form rails gem.

1.

Is there a better way to automatically translate static array from model in input collection?

```
OPTIONS = [:val1,:val2,:val3] #constant from my model:
#for now i'm doing this:        
f.collection_radio :model_attribute, MyModel::OPTIONS .collect { |o| [t(o, :scope=>[:activerecord, :attributes, :MyModel]), "#{o}"] }, :last, :first %>
```

1. How i can display bitmask attribute with checkboxes? (Bruce bitmask)

Answer (score 2):

1) [simple_form supports I18n for options](http://simple-form.plataformatec.com.br/#i18n). You just pass an array of symbols and the translations will be looked up as follows:

```
en:
  simple_form:
    options:
      model:
        model_attribute:
          val1: 'Value 1'
          val2: 'Value 2'
          val3: 'Value 3'
```

2) `f.input :roles, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => User.values_for_roles`, translate as above

Answer (score 0):

1. `f.input :attribute, :collection => YourModel::OPTIONS.collect`
2. `f.input :roles, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => User.roles.collect`